# Global set node background

Tags: tikz-pgf

I know I can do this:

```
\draw (5,0) node[above=3pt,fill=white,inner sep=0pt] {$5$}
```

But I wonder if it is possible to set the `3pt`, `fill=white`, and `inner sep=0pt` globally for every node in my document?

Thanks.

Comment: Let's say I want to offset each node by 3pt. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\tikzset` in the preamble for global options. A style that is used for every node is called `every node`. You need to use one of the following handlers to change/add keys to the style:

- `.style`: overwrites the current definition of the style;
- `.append style`: appends a set of keys to the current definition;
- `.prefix style`: prefixes a set of keys to the current definition.

By default, the `every node` style is empty/undefined when TikZ is loaded so you can actually use all of those keys without a difference.

---

But just for later reference (you can also alter the `every node` style at the beginning of a TikZ picture, a `scope` environment or in a `\path`, let’s have an example.

Let us assume that the `every node` style has been defined similar to

```
\tikzset{every node/.style={draw=green, fill=blue}}
```

Every node now will have its path drawn in green and filled in blue.
A TikZ picture that starts with

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={shape=circle}]
```

will be of the shape `circle` but neither drawn nor filled as the previous style has been overwritten due to the `.style` handler.

The declarations

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={shape=circle}]
```

and

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.prefix style={shape=circle}]
```

will both result in nodes of a circular shape that has been drawn and filled in green and blue respectively. There is no difference (in the outcome) between `.append` and `.prefix` as the keys `shape`, `draw` and `fill` are independent of each other.

A declaration like

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={draw=red}]
```

will change the definition of `every node` to

```
draw=green, fill=blue, draw=red
```

The first `draw` key is not overwritten per se as it is still executed when a node is created but the second `draw` key overwrites the changes/settings the previous occurrence made. (In this case, the command `\tikz@mode@drawtrue` is added twice to `\tikz@mode` and thus executed twice when TikZ finished the path but this doesn’t affect anything.)

The declaration

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.prefix style={fill=red}]
```

will not result in nodes that are filled with the color red as the definition of `every node` has changed to

```
fill=red, draw=green, fill=blue
```

The latter `fill=blue` overwrites the changes/settings of `fill=red`.

Using keys multiple times in styles do usually not have any side effects as they simply set certain settings but their effects can accumulate. For example, the use of `xshift=1cm, xshift=2cm` will result in a total transformation of `3cm`.